# Keeping entity relationship in sync when deleting child in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity-relationship

I've read that you need to keep entities that have a relationship in sync, i.e. when you remove a child from a parent you should also set the attribute that holds the parent to null in the child entity. In my example I have the following parent entity:

```
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

And the child:

```
public class Child {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The code for removing a child from the parent is as follows (in this example a `Parent` can have the same `Child` in its list multiple times):

```
public void removeChild(Child child) {
    List<Child> childrenToRemove = this.children.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.equals(child))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    childrenToRemove.forEach(child -> child.setParent(null));
    this.children.removeAll(childrenToRemove);
}
```

I first set the `Parent` to NULL on each of the children and then remove them from the collection. This keeps the entities in sync. What I could also do is change the `removeChild` code to the following:

```
public void removeChild(Child child) {
    this.children.removeIf(c -> c.equals(child));
}
```

Of course in this case the entities are not kept in sync because each of those `Child` entities still has a reference to the `Parent`. To remedy that I could add the following to the `Child` entity:

```
@PreRemove
public void preRemove() {
    this.parent = null;
}
```

My question now is, what if `Child` entity is also kept in a list of a different parent entity, e.g. the entity `AnotherParent` which also keeps a list of `Child` entities, should I then also add `this.anotherParent = null` to the `@PreRemove` method defined above? What if `Child` has unidirectional relationship with other entities (i.e. the other side doesn't keep a list of the `Child` entities, should they be set to null?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the bidirectional associations in sync so that the entity state transitions can propagate and to avoid hard-to-track bugs in your code.

> My question now is, what if Child entity is also kept in a list of a
> different parent entity, e.g. the entity AnotherParent which also
> keeps a list of Child entities, should I then also add
> this.anotherParent = null to the @PreRemove method defined above?

If the `AnotherParent` entity is not loaded in the currently running Persistence cOntext, you don't have to do that because the parent-side collection does not exist in memory.

> What if Child has unidirectional relationship with other entities
> (i.e. the other side doesn't keep a list of the Child entities, should
> they be set to null?).

If you don't do that, you'll get a `ConstraintViolationException` because unidirectional associations are more like many-to-many than one-to-many.

Comment: That makes sense, I do wonder how you would know whether or not `AnotherParent` is currently loaded in the running PC?

Comment: You have to inspect the data access logic. This is handled on a per use case-basis.